# Evaluating state derivatives for Model Exchange FMU within the same step

Tags: c, fmi

I am trying to create a custom solver for a Model Exchange (ME) FMU, using the fmilib in C, tag 2.3. The solver I am trying to implement is a Runge-Kutta order 2, The Heun method, as seen in the formulas given in the picture: [Heun Method Order 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t0gx.png).

I start by making sure I am in continuous time mode with a call to `fmi2_import_enter_continuous_time_mode()`. Then, I get equation (2) with a call to `fmi2_import_get_derivatives()`. After this, I need to compute equations (3) and (4), for which I do:

```
    //FORWARD EULER estimation for ui+1
    for (k = 0; k < n_states; k++) {
      //States derivatives from EQUATION (2)
      states[k] = states_previous[k] + h*states_derivatives[k]; 
    }
    
    //Set the current state estimations to the model
    fmi2_import_set_continuous_states(fmu, states, n_states);

    //EQUATION (3), the derivatives of the model with the estimated states
    fmistatus = fmi2_import_set_time(fmu, t + h);
    fmistatus = fmi2_import_get_derivatives(fmu, temp_state_derivatives, n_states);
    fmistatus = fmi2_import_set_time(fmu, t);

    //EQUATION (4), HEUN METHOD ORDER 2 - Computing the actual states
    for (k = 0; k < n_states; k++) {
      states[k] = states_previous[k] + h*0.5*(temp_state_derivatives[k] + states_derivatives[k]);
    }

    //Set the actual ui+1 estimate of the states to the model
    fmistatus = fmi2_import_set_continuous_states(fmu, states, n_states);
```

All of the above works without any issues, however, if I try to call `fmi2_import_get_derivatives()` after the last time I set the states, I get the same derivative values as in equation (3). How is this possible? An update to the model states should also imply an update to the derivatives, as per equation (1). Where did I go wrong in this procedure?

Comment: Why do you set the time back to `t`? The new state is for time `t+h`, which is already set.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I set `t+h` because I want to calculate the derivatives then. I do not really know what is happening in the FMU when the derivatives are calculated so I decided it was better to be safe than sorry. I go back in time for the sake of consistency since my main step loop increments time after `fmi2_import_set_continuous_states()` is called. I have played around with not setting time at all, or leaving it at `t+h` and that does not change the outcomes.

Comment: It seems strange things happen in the background, https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMIKit-Simulink/issues/111. On the surface, there is nothing objectionable in the lines you presented. Do you have an Euler method implementation or any other example that works correctly? I found that fmi version 3.0 already exists, can you use that and does it work better?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I had tried a Forward Euler previously, and th Heun method was giving the same results. This was bothering me, because it seemed like it was working but the derivatives were not updated. I got access to the equations of the model today, and made some calculations by hand. **Given the nature of the equations, what the FMU does is correct, the derivatives should not have changed**. I guess this settles things, then. Thank you for your input!